# What is the centre hole for in modern train tracks?

Tags: trains

LEGO train tracks have 3 holes in each of the segments:

[image: Train Tracks]

I understand the two outer holes are used with a throw-away piece to keep  them stacked while shipping, but what is the center hole for? Is it just for saving a bit of plastic? Or perhaps just a planned 'shipping' feature that was never used?

Comment: Throw-away piece? Throw-away piece? You don't throw away LEGO parts!!!

Comment: Indeed, you keep those pieces to keep your rail bits in line in storage.

Comment: I bet you keep the bit in the middle of the coin sprue too :) .  Seriously though, use a longer metal piece to hold more tracks together.  The plastic holder is just a waste of space, and seeing as it's crimped on the end it *looks* bitten.  No bite marks in my collection thank you.

Comment: I'm just saying, I used on of these in a MOC once.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The larger hole is present in older 9V track as well:

[image: 9v curved track]

I've never actually done this, but I've always assumed that the hole is there so that the track can be screwed or nailed down if desired to create a semi-permanent layout. This is common practice with traditional model railroad track:

[image: HO track with nails]

Comment: I'm fairly confident that's the reason. There was a hole in [12v gray sleepers](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=767) as well, by the way.

Comment: I suppose it makes sense with the curved rail pieces since they don't clutch directly on to a baseplate in the way straight pieces do. It

Comment: Given that even a large track layout doesn't weigh much, and the train itself does, the track can slip around quite a bit as the train goes around corners, unless the track is secured to the surface or weighted down with attachments. I am fairly sure that this is what that hole is for. It's even tapered, to fit a screw head or nail head flush.

Comment: Yeah, the countersunk nature of the hole makes me pretty certain this is for screws/nails.  Not sure why I didn't think of it earlier :)

Comment: The countersinking does as said give the likely reason. Interestingly (or not) I noted a picture of a piece of track via LDdaw in another question and you could just about make out the fact the central hole on that generated image was countersunk too.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 try making a circle and running even a single citytrain on full speed - if your floor/table is smooth enough, the train will just spin mostly in place with the track flying around, it's quite funny to watch but definitely not the point :)